# VS 2013 : console output not corresponding to open program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console, visual-studio-2013

I'm new to Visual Studio, and haven't done any programming in a number of months, so I'm a bit rusty. I was previously using Code::Blocks but my computer science class demands VS 2013.

So I started with a simple hello world program just to test that VS was functioning normally, it output exactly what I wrote. I then went on to building the basic structure of the program for my first assignment of writing a program which calculates the volume of sphere.

Made it extra simple to test input/output, console's output doesn't make any sense to me:

[image: output]

I don't at all understand why it is still outputting "Hello world" when that line isn't even present in my code. I tried saving and building it before hitting ctrl + F5, and it still comes out as "Hello world."

Comment: Your code has errors (see notifications below) and was never successfully compiled.

Answer (score 2):

Your IDE clearly shows you that you have a compilation error.

```
cin >> radius >> endl;
              ^^
```

You cannot use `std::endl` with `std::cin`

Change it to:

```
cin >> radius;
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I knew that whatever the reason was it was idiotic, haha. So when the most recent build of a program doesn't compile properly it just defaults to running the previous build or something? Why else would it show "Hello world"?

Comment: Normally it does not and asks you, but you probably clicked once yes and there was some checkbox for remembering it. Now it does not ask you but runs it. Somewhere in the settings this can be changed back, but unfortunately I don't recall where it was. Tools -> Options -> something